# SqlException was unhandled by user code using connection string

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm following the ASP.NET MVC 5 Tutorial and everything was fine until I added the connection string:

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

After this I built the project and when I access http://localhost:port/Movies, it throws an error:

> SQL exception was unhandled by user code

right here:

```
    // GET: Movies
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Movies.ToList()); // <- Here
    }
```

Either the database is not created or I failed to link it. The `Movies.mdf` file wasn't added to the `App_Data` folder as well. I guess this should already been done at this point?

I've looked everywhere but I haven't seen anyone with this problem using connection strings in the `web.config` file like it is described in the tutorial. Is this technique deprecated, or is there any other way of doing this?

I'm using VS2015 btw.

Comment: What is the *full* exception text? Did you try debugging? What you posted is the YSOD title, not the exception text. Besides, what does `The Movies.mdf file wasn't added to the App_Data folder` mean? Did you simply add the connection string without adding the file to the project?

Comment: Did you check if localdb is installed ? It doesn't get installed by default with VS. You can go to add/remove programs and change VS installation or get LocalDb installation separately or use SQLExpress instead of LocalDb.

Comment: @CetinBasoz That's my concern as well I'm checking it now.

Comment: @CetinBasoz That was the issue! Now it runs.